# Convert list of strings to dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, split

I have a list

```
['Tests run: 1', ' Failures: 0', ' Errors: 0']
```

I would like to convert it to a dictionary as

```
{'Tests run': 1, 'Failures': 0, 'Errors': 0}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
a = ['Tests run: 1', ' Failures: 0', ' Errors: 0']

d = {}
for b in a:
    i = b.split(': ')
    d[i[0]] = i[1]

print d
```

returns:

```
{' Failures': '0', 'Tests run': '1', ' Errors': '0'}
```

If you want integers, change the assignment in:

```
d[i[0]] = int(i[1])
```

This will give:

```
{' Failures': 0, 'Tests run': 1, ' Errors': 0}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
In [35]: a = ['Tests run: 1', ' Failures: 0', ' Errors: 0']

In [36]: {i.split(':')[0]: int(i.split(':')[1]) for i in a}
Out[36]: {'Tests run': 1, ' Failures': 0, ' Errors': 0}

In [37]:
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = ['Tests run: 1', ' Failures: 0', ' Errors: 0']
b = dict([i.split(': ') for i in a])
final = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in b.items())  # or iteritems instead of items in Python 2
print(final)
```

#### Result

```
{' Failures': 0, 'Tests run': 1, ' Errors': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

naive solution assuming you have a clean dataset:

```
intconv = lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1]))

dict(intconv(i.split(': ')) for i in your_list)
```

This assumes that you do not have duplicates and you don't have other colons in there.

What happens is that you first split the strings into a tuple of two values. You do this here with a generator expression.  You can pass this directly into the dict, since a dict knows how to handle an iterable yielding tuples of length 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = ['Tests run: 1', ' Failures: 0', ' Errors: 0']
d = dict([map(str.strip, i.split(':')) for i in l])
for key, value in d.items():
    d[key] = int(value)
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'Tests run': 1, 'Errors': 0, 'Failures': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over your list, and split by the colon. Then assign the first value to the second value in a dict object:

```
x = ['Tests run: 1', ' Failures: 0', ' Errors: 0']
y = {}
for k in x:
    c = k.split(':')
    y[str(c[0]).replace(" ", "")] = str(c[-1]).replace(" ", "")

print(y)
#{'Failures': '0', 'Tests run': '1', 'Errors': '0'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = ['Tests run: 1', ' Failures: 0', ' Errors: 0']
>>> {i.split(":")[0].strip():int(i.split(":")[1].strip()) for i in s}
{' Failures': 0, 'Tests run': 1, ' Errors': 0}
```