# Get Number after a text in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I need some help with getting numbers after a certain text
For example, I have a list:

```
  ['Martin 9', '    Leo 2 10', '    Elisabeth 3']
```

Now I need to change the list into variables like this:

```
Martin = 9
Leo2 =10
Elisabeth = 3
```

I didn't tried many things, because I'm new to  Python.

Thanks for reading my question and probably helping me

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with [tag:Selenium], it's purely a String parsing problem?

Comment: Yeah but the list is out of selenium so I wrote it down there sorry

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant HTML, the code you've tried, and a better description of what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: The HTML is a different language. I didn't tried any working code and I want to get a the "Leo 10" to a variables Leo = 10

Comment: It sounds like you want some type of list of tuples or a dictionary, where you can get the number based on the name. Maybe that'll help in googling :) If this is still unanswered tomorrow I may try to find some time at a solution. Welcome to stack!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I edited the question a bit, so I hope it's easier to understand.

Comment: I have the solution, i'll post it in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you get some list with using selenium so getting integer from list works without using `re` like :

```
list = ["Martin 9","Leo 10","Elisabeth 3"]
for a in list:

    print ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, a))
```

Output :

```
9
10
3
```

Comment: I don't have the list "word","word", it's written in Line by line. And then I only want the number after Martin not everyone. To specify it more: I'm trying to automate a Webgame with selenium and there I have to send cars. How many cars and what type of car is written in a list there.

Comment: `print type(value)` if is string remove for condition just use `' '.join... `is list or array use the above code

Comment: I'll try to say what variables I need there out of this list. I need Martin = 9 Leo =10 and Elisabeth =3

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you loaded it from a file and got it line by line:

```
numbers = []
for line in lines:
   line = line.split()
   if line[0] == "Martin": numbers.append(int(line[1]))
```

Comment: Is there a way without writing all ifs?

Comment: In case you got a list `names` with all the names you want to get use `if line[0] in names: numbers.append(int(line[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want a bunch of variables, especially if the list grows large. Instead I think you want a `dictionary` where the names are the key and the number is the value.

I would start by splitting your `string` into a `list` as described [in this question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042948/split-string-using-a-newline-delimiter-with-python)

```
s=
  "Martin 9
  Leo 10
  Elisabeth 3"
listData = data.splitlines()
```

Then I would turn that `list` into a `dictionary` as described [in this question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980977/convert-list-of-strings-to-dictionary)

```
myDictionary = {}
for listItem in listData:
    i = listItem.split(' ')
    myDictionary[i[0]] = int(i[1])
```

Then you can access the number, in Leo's case `10`, via:

```
myDictionary["Leo"]
```

I have not tested this syntax and I'm not used to python, so I'm sure a little debugging will be involved. Let me know if I need to make some corrections.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Or, maybe you really want a list of person [objects](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) that stores the name and number so you don't have to deal with typos.

Comment: Looks like the original question was changed to add additional spaces and characters (ie. `Leo 2 10`). That makes things more complicated and this answer is now only a partial solution. At this point you might want to research how to split the last word off of a line (instead of by space in this answer from this line `listItem.split(' ')`) to get the number separate and combine that with this answer.

Comment: Additional note... turning the data into variables (ie. `"Leo"` becoming a variable `leo`) is not really how variables are used in programming, which is why nobody is really giving any insight in how to do that. Variables are typically more abstract representations of the data they hold. While that's not strictly true, it's hard to imagine how your data set would be an exception to that. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
s="""Leo 1 9
Leo 2 2"""
```

I shortened the list here

look for the word in the list:
    if "Leo 1" in s:
then get the index of it:

```
i = s.index("Leo 1")
```

then add the number of character of the word

```
lenght=len("Leo 1")
```

And then add it: (+1 because of the space)

```
b = i + lenght + 1
```

and then get the number on the position b:

```
x = int(s[b]
```

so in total:

```
if "Leo 1" in s:
  i = s.index("Leo 1")
  lenght = len("Leo 1")
  b = i + lenght + 1
  x = int(s[b])
```